# Is it required to test public inner classes?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Should I test public inner classes public methods ? Or I should test outer class public methods, which uses inner class (same approach as testing  private methods)?

Comment: You have to test every method you write (irrespective whether it's inside or outside).

Comment: You should especially test any method/functionality which is not already tested by the outer class.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman - absolutely not.  There's no point testing methods that are one or two lines long and have no branching or looping logic.  There's no point testing private methods when the only calling methods have already been tested.

Comment: "You have to test every method you write"   even private methods?

Comment: @David Wallace, I'm referring to functional testing. Whether the method is private/public/protected, you need test cases to show that these method follows functional and business requirements. Even if you test your public method (that calls your private method), chances are, you will still need to test the private method that will determine whether your public method passes/fails.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman - I disagree completely.  There shouldn't be business requirements for what your private methods do.  Typically, a private method is just to make your implementation simpler.  Test whether the SUT meets its business requirements; and if your private methods are needed, they will get run as part of the test, but there won't be tests that focus only on the private methods.  If you base your tests around which methods you've got, you run the risk of missing whole chunks of functionality that your SUT ought to provide, but doesn't.

Comment: @David Wallace, you can have private methods for **internal system purpose** functionality, that's not needed by the client but crucial to the system. You mean that you won't test that method functionality?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman - I will test every requirement of the class, by calling public or protected methods.  It doesn't matter whether the requirements relate to client-visible functionality or internal-system functionality.  I won't write test cases that call the private methods directly.  My tests will be based around how the requirements are expressed, not around how they have been implemented.  Is that clearer?

Comment: @David Wallace, requirements can be functional/non-functional requirements. Both needs to be tested (whether some functionality are public to client or not), that's what I'm saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to test everything that is accessible from outside your class. This includes public methods of inner classes (whether or not the classes themselves are public or private).

If you're exposing a method, you need to test it.

Answer (score 3):

If the outer class method merely delegates the call to the inner class one, you may test just one of them. It doesn't really matter which one. In this case you may want to rethink your design though - excessive delegation implies bad design in my experience.

If the outer class method does something else which is significant other than just calling the inner class method, then you should test them both separately like this:

- Test just inner class method
- Test just outer class method with inner class method mocked (if possible)
- Test outer class method

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is "required". You need to make sensible testing, but focus on **functional testing**, not lines coverage: everything your code does should be tested one way or another.

If there's any business logic in your inner class methods, then it may help testing these directly (and turning the inner to a top level class). Depending on what it does, testing the outside may be enough, if you do that you introduce coupling in your test coverage, but as the class is an inner class the coupling is already there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should test that your classes meet all of their requirements, regardless of how those requirements have been implemented.  Do NOT write a test for each method; rather, work out what tests you need based on what requirements have been implemented, and whether there are different cases that are covered by each requirement.  Whether you have written inner classes, private methods and so forth is kind of irrelevant to the testing process.